# How to achieve parallelism with kafka connect source?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I'm fairly new to Kafka connect. I'm planning to use kafka connect source to read data from my MySQL database tables into one of the kafka topics. Now, since my source table is a transactional data store, i might get a new record inserted into it or  a record might be updated. Now, I'm trying to understand how can i achieve parallelism to read the data from this table and my question is,

1. Can i use max.tasks to achieve parallelism (have more than one thread) to read the data and push onto the kafka topic?  If yes, Please explain.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean parallelism to read multiple partitions from a table at once? Or what exactly?

Comment: parallelism to read more records from the database table